# Is there a term in Italian for someone who is always borrowing money from friends or relatives and never pays them back?

Tags: idioms, phrase-request

I'm looking for a slang-word or idiom, with emphasis on the fact that the person never pays his debts.  Such a person is always borrowing small amounts from friends and relatives (say, €20 or €50) because he knows it's much easier to get away with it. It can also involve bank loans and credit cards, but the main fact is that he is notorious for not paying back small amounts he borrows from friends. The term I'm looking for is a noun and would be used in a sentence such as this:

Attenzione, perché Giuseppe è un _____________ben noto.

Comment: What does the simbol “E$” mean?

Comment: E = Euro.  My keybord has no character for the Euro.

Comment: Ah, okay, I was in doubt whether you meant euros or some other currency. Let me fix it for you.

Comment: http://eurosymbol.eu/keyboard

Comment: ... and to get any symbol, for example the degree symbol, just Google "degree symbol", then copy and paste.

Comment: Question has already been well-answered, but there is the possibility of using the expression "uno che fa (un sacco di) debiti", literally "one who indebts himself (a lot)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest ***[scroccone](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/scroccone.shtml)***:

> - Chi ha l'abitudine di far pagare sempre gli altri o di ottenere qlco. gratis.

Sabatini Coletti

Comment: “Scroccone” has a more general meaning than what the OP is looking. A *scroccone* might want to eat for free and the like, rather than specifically borrow money with no intention to repay it.

Comment: @DaG -  yes but that is the term I'd use in the context OP is describing. I don't think there is a "money specific" term.

Comment: At this is the term I'd use in this situation, and honestly if someone behaves like that with money, s/he will probably do the same for non-monetary things too...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean only that a *scroccone* tries probably to get meals more than money, but mainly that the behaviour described by the OP is very specific, while *scroccone* is more generic. Who behaves like in the question is probably a *scroccone*, but certainly not all *scrocconi* behave in that manner. All giraffes are mammals, but not all mammals are giraffes.

Comment: @DaG -  I agree, but I have to insist that "scroccone" still appears the best fit here. Any other suggestion is wellcome of course.

Comment: I could also suggest "parassita", but I would prefer "scroccone".

Answer (score 1):

An expression that can be alternatively used instead of "scroccone" or "parassita " could also be "mangiapane a tradimento", with the meaning of profiteer. 
It also exists the expression "mangiatore a sbafo" with a similar meaning.

Comment: "parassita" is a word I know well.  It can be applied to someone who lives at the expenses of (an)other(s) but is not specific for those who borrow money and never pay their debts.